# The new Music StackExchange Beta site could benefit from the Physics community

Tags: discussion

(Shameless one-time call to participation to another S.E. site)

Tuesday, May 3rd was the first day for the public Beta of [music.SE](http://music.stackexchange.com), [**Music Practice and Performance**](http://music.stackexchange.com).

Many interesting **physics** questions are associated with musical instruments. Some fundamental physical concepts were born out of the investigation of sound, vibration, strings, tension.

One of the current questions relevant to **physics** in music.SE is this one

[Why are violin bows longer than viola bows, than cello bows, than double-bass bows ?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/74/48)

And it would be nice that more questions about the physics of instruments and instrument playing be asked and answered on the site.

I believe members from Physics.SE could valuably contribute to this new site, as physicists making this kind of questions and answers more precise and more informed and of course as musicians when this is the case, even as lurker.

As usual, Physics accounts holders with at least 200 points who create an associated account through OpenID on music.SE will have a 100 point starting bonus on the new site.

So you are [welcome](http://music.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these sorts of announcements, I'm just going to close it because it's not really something that can be answered, and this way it doesn't pollute our unanswered questions list.